# Alias route for same controller action in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails routes...

I'm trying to create an alias route for my

```
resources :users
```

^ `/users/123`

My goal is to add a `/granted` at the end of the URL so something like `/users/123/granted`

I'm trying to add a `get` to create another route for the same controller action... I need this for the SEO

```
get '/users/:id/granted', to: 'users#show', as: :granted
```

^ I'm expecting this to generate `/users/:id/granted` but I keep getting...

`/users/:user_id/users/:id/granted`

Looks like it's attaching a different format, with `:user_id` as the parameter... but I need the parameter to stay as `:id`

I tried

`get '/granted', to: 'users#show', as: :granted`

it generates `/users/:user_id/granted` which is not okay because as I mentioned above... I want the parameter key to stay as `:id`

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you need to sort things out for 2 tasks: defining a new route (`/users/:id/granted`) and making the route an alias for an existing controller action (`users#show`).

Before that, let me help you getting familiar with one of the Rails best practices **when you need to add more custom actions to a RESTful resource (other than the 7 default actions created by `resources :users`) -- use [`member`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) and [`collection`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) routes.**

So, to add `/granted` member route inside the `users` resource, you can write:

```
resources :users do
  get 'granted', on: :member
end
```

Moreover, to point the newly added route to an existing controller action (`users#show`, in your case), just pass it over `:to` option:

```
resources :users do
  get 'granted', to: 'users#show', on: :member
end
```

If you have other existing member routes under the `users` resource, then add the route inside the `member` block instead:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    # other custom member routes
    get 'granted', to: 'users#show'
  end
end
```

`rake routes` output for your specific `granted` route:

```
granted_user GET    /users/:id/granted(.:format) users#show
```

Answer (score 0):

For things to work exactly like you would want, do this instead -

```
resources :users
get '/users/:id/granted', to: 'users#show', as: :granted
```

Comment: Sorry... I also need the normal route from resources. I need them 2 to be accessible. Thanks @bitsapien

Comment: In that case your code should work. I've edited my answer, try that and paste the result of `rake routes`.

Comment: getting something like `user_granted GET  /users/:user_id/users/:id/granted(.:format) users#show` @bitsapient

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are enclosing your route definition inside a resource block like this - 
`resources :users do
  get '/users/:id/granted', to: 'users#show', as: :granted
end
`
Change it to what I've suggested above.

Comment: yeah there's a `collection` and `member` inside the resources block. I ended up specifying this `get :granted, to: 'users#show'` inside the `member` block. Thanks for taking time... @bitsapien